# C# - Accessing methods from another class within other classes?

Tags: c#, class

I have recently started my journey to learn C# so I'm in no way an expert.
Anyways, I tried to create an object-oriented calculator but I've run in to a problem where it seems like I can't access methods from other classes within certain classes. I get no error codes but when I put a breakpoint down and debug the application the value of the variables are 0.

If I remove the method from DisplayUserData and paste the code in my main program file, it runs fine. It seems like the DisplayUserData class can't pass the variables or retrieve variables from other classes, why is this?

Oh and, excuse the horrible method, class and variable names.

Here is my main program file:

```
namespace Calculator
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            GetUserInput userInput = new GetUserInput();
            Calculator calculator = new Calculator();
            DisplayUserData displayUserCalculation = new DisplayUserData();


            userInput.MethodOfCalculation();
            userInput.UserNumberInput();
            displayUserCalculation.DisplayCalculatedUserData();

        }
    }
}
```

Followed by my GetUserInput class:

```
namespace Calculator
{
    public class GetUserInput
    {
        public char Choice;
        public decimal ValueOne;
        public decimal ValueTwo;

        public void MethodOfCalculation()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Welcome to Calculator v.1!");
            Console.WriteLine("Please choose a method of calculation below.");
            Console.WriteLine("1: Addition");
            Console.WriteLine("2: Subtraction");
            Console.Write("Your choice: ");
            Choice = Console.ReadKey().KeyChar;
        }

        public void UserNumberInput()
        {
            Console.Clear();
            Console.WriteLine("Please enter two numbers for calculation!");
            Console.Write("Number One: ");
            ValueOne = Convert.ToDecimal(Console.ReadLine());
            Console.Write("Number Two: ");
            ValueTwo = Convert.ToDecimal(Console.ReadLine());
        }

    }
}
```

And the Calculator class:

```
namespace Calculator
{
    public class Calculator
    {
        public decimal CalculateUserInput(char userChoice, decimal valueOne, decimal valueTwo)
        {
            decimal calculatedValue = 0;

            switch (userChoice)
            {
                case '1':
                    calculatedValue = valueOne + valueTwo;
                    break;
                case '2':
                    calculatedValue = valueOne - valueTwo;
                    break;
            }

            return calculatedValue;
        }
    }
}
```

And lastly the DisplayUserData class:

```
namespace Calculator
{
    class DisplayUserData
    {
        GetUserInput _userInput = new GetUserInput();
        Calculator _calculator = new Calculator();

        public void DisplayCalculatedUserData()
        {
            decimal calculatedValue = _calculator.CalculateUserInput(_userInput.Choice, _userInput.ValueOne, _userInput.ValueTwo);

            switch (_userInput.Choice)
            {
                case '1':
                    Console.WriteLine("Addition: " + _userInput.ValueOne + " + " + _userInput.ValueTwo + " = " + calculatedValue);
                    break;
                case '2':
                    Console.WriteLine("Subtraction: " + _userInput.ValueOne + " - " + _userInput.ValueTwo + " = " + calculatedValue);
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

You are creating new versions (instances) of the `UserInput` and `Calculator` classes in your `DisplayUserData` class. Because you were using new instances, those instances didn't have access to the data contained in the instances used in your main method. Instead of creating the new instances in your class, pass the existing instances in through a constructor for the class to use.

```
namespace Calculator
{
    class DisplayUserData
    {
        private readonly GetUserInput _userInput;
        private readonly Calculator _calculator;

        DisplayUserData(GetUserInput userInput, Calculator calculator)
        {
            _userInput = userInput;
            _calculator = calculator;
        }

        public void DisplayCalculatedUserData()
        {
            decimal calculatedValue = _calculator.CalculateUserInput(_userInput.Choice, _userInput.ValueOne, _userInput.ValueTwo);

            switch (_userInput.Choice)
            {
                case '1':
                    Console.WriteLine("Addition: " + _userInput.ValueOne + " + " + _userInput.ValueTwo + " = " + calculatedValue);
                    break;
                case '2':
                    Console.WriteLine("Subtraction: " + _userInput.ValueOne + " - " + _userInput.ValueTwo + " = " + calculatedValue);
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Then call it as

```
displayUserCalculation.DisplayCalculatedUserData(userInput, calculator);
```

Answer (score 3):

Your DisplayUserData class has references to different Calculator and GetUserInput classes than the ones that your Program refers to. You should pass the same instances to DisplayUserData like this.

```
class DisplayUserData
{
    readonly GetUserInput _userInput;
    readonly Calculator _calculator;

    public DisplayUserData(Calculator calculator, GetUserInput userInput)
    {
        _calculator = calculator;
        _userInput = userInput;
    }

    public void DisplayCalculatedUserData()
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

Program would then be:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        GetUserInput userInput = new GetUserInput();
        Calculator calculator = new Calculator();
        DisplayUserData displayUserCalculation = new DisplayUserData(calculator, userInput);

        userInput.MethodOfCalculation();
        userInput.UserNumberInput();
        displayUserCalculation.DisplayCalculatedUserData();

    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for taking your time to reply. Just one question though, what does this part of the code do now? `readonly GetUserInput _userInput;
    readonly Calculator _calculator;` What am I defining there? I'm only familiar with for example `Calculator _calculator = new Calculator();` Am I defining an entire copy of the class and it's contents?

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, that piece of code is just referring to the object without creating a new instance of it? And then we assign the value to it when we create an object of DisplayUserData in the main program? Are we passing the entire contents of the classes through?

Comment: Yes that is correct. You are just storing the reference to your Calculator and GetUserInput classes (with it's current state and contents). That way the dependent object (DisplayUserData) will have access to the correct instances of those objects.